# Apache - PHP Files Are Returned Black, Not Even HTML in php File Displaying

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 10.04 and my apache2 server has been running for a couple of days now.

I have created a new directory called 'xmlscores' and when I run any PHP file inside of this directory nothing gets returned, not even my HTML that is inside of the page.

Note: Other File Types open correctly in the browser (I have tried HTML & XML).

This suggests to me that the php code is not even interpreted and thus not even sent to my apache server - my browser, by default, returns blank page (source is blank)

Note: The problem is not with my php code, as I have tried multiple files and none have worked.

Comment: Check the server error_log file for any messages.  If the HTTP code returned when you request any of those pages is `500`, then there is a configuration error or a fatal error in the php code.

Comment: WHat happens when your PHP file is just `<?php echo ("Hi"); ?>`? Is there any output then?

Comment: @AlexHowansky the file is 'scores.php'

Comment: `This suggests to me that the php code is not even interpreted` - this is definitely not the case, if your PHP code is not being interpreted then you would see your PHP source code when you view source.

Comment: Have you been able to run PHP scripts outside of that directory?

Comment: for a couple of days? Did you install it? Have you configured anything during install?

Comment: "I have created a new directory called 'xmlscores' and when I run any PHP file inside of this directory..."   I suggest you rename the directory.

Comment: @Alfabravo I installed it three days ago and have not configured it further

Comment: Check httpd.conf, apache2.conf or /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf to see if mod-php5.so is enabled

Comment: @JackWink .php files which have been created prior to my first problem can still be executed anywhere (in or outside of this directory).

The error seems to occur with the php files which i have created post my initial error

Comment: Have you tried turning on error reporting at the top of your script? It might give some clues. <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1); echo "it works!"; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Check your Apache Error logs, ensure the entire version of PHP is installed

If you're using Debian/Ubuntu you can run

```
apt-get install php5
```